# Selecting a range of values in a specific column for R ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, subset

I am trying to select a range of values (i.e. the first 4 values) in a specific column from a table. The column is called "RL45". I tried the following code to create a plot in ggplot:

```
newplot <- ggplot(data = GEV, aes(x = RL45[1:4])) + geom_density(color = 
"midnightblue") + xlab("Location (mm/day") + ggtitle("Global Location under RCP4.5") + 
xlim(300, 350)
```

This results in this strange error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (34): x
```

This is odd, as I selected the first 4 values in that "RL45" column.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to change where you subset.

```
newplot <- ggplot(data = GEV[1:4,], aes(x = RL45)) + geom_density(color = 
    "midnightblue") + xlab("Location (mm/day") + ggtitle("Global Location under RCP4.5") + 
    xlim(300, 350)
```

Comment: @Steve Graves - that you so much! Yes, this stopped the error from appearing. From what I see, though, when I attempt to change the subset from [1:4] to, say, [17:21] or [30:34], I end up with the exact same plots. Why could that be? The idea would be to make different curves on the same plot by changing the subset.

Comment: Ah, nevermind - I found the issue with that - I left out the comma after the range specified. Thanks, again!